# Get records that don't have their ID in a seperate String Set - DynamoDB

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Amazon Dynamo DB to down load a number of records to Android.

I have 2 Tables.

Table 1 contains a Set of Strings containing ID's
Table 2 has records each with an individual ID.

I want to download 10 records from Table 2 **only if the record ID does not appear in the Set of strings in Table 1.**

I can do this by downloading all the records in table 2 and then not saving /displaying the ones that appear in the String Set in table 1. However is there a way to only download the ones that don't appear in the String Set?

Any ideals would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: You're trying to think of DynamoDB as a relational database where this would be super easy to do. DynamDB (NoSQL) does not have a concept of relationships. But one way to do this with DynamoDB would be to add an extra attribute to Table 1 to include the data you need. Duplicated data is not always a bad thing with NoSQL DBs.

Answer (score 0):

In order to query a dynamodb you need the attribute to either be a range key or partition key which in terns need to be scalar so you cannot directly query what you want. Your best chance of doing what you want if I understand your requirement is scan operation. Scan the whole table(2) and then use queryExpression to filter the results you get using a nested query in table one. This demands you to make the "Set of Strings" either either partition or range key in your first table.